# Script with curl doesn't work from crontab on FreeBSD

Tags: cron, freebsd, curl

I have `bash` script:

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/curl ifconfig.io --interface tun15071 -m 15 -w "%{http_code}\n" > /home/user/out
```

... and the following crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
* * * * * /home/user/cron_ch.sh
```

Cron does the job, but it does not change the file
If I run the script manually from the console, the file will change

Cron log:

```
Aug  5 09:57:00 GAME2 /usr/sbin/cron[66337]: (user) CMD (/home/user/cron_ch.sh)
```

I found information on the net that this could be due to the difference between the environment of cron and the user.
I don't see any variables that could be a solution to this

```bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
TERM=xterm
MAIL=/var/mail/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
USERNAME=root
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/csh
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
SUDO_USER=user
SUDO_UID=1022
SUDO_GID=1022
HOSTTYPE=FreeBSD
VENDOR=amd
OSTYPE=FreeBSD
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PWD=/home/mateo
GROUP=wheel
HOST=name
REMOTEHOST=255.255.255.255
EDITOR=vi
PAGER=more
BLOCKSIZE=K
```

The user have no mail from cron.
Cron performs tasks for other users.

Comment: Is `ifconfig.io` a web address? Do you want to add the protocol, like `http://`? It's unlikely to help but could make it easier to read. Also, is the output intended to go to `/home/user/out`? You seem to want to run the cron job as root (why?)?

Comment: Do you get any error output mailed to you by the cron daemon? If you also redirect the error stream to you log file (by adding `2>&1` at the very end of the command in the script), do you get any further insight into what goes wrong? Are you certain you schedule the script, not the `curl` command (the `curl` command uses `%` which must be escaped if it's used in the cron schedule itself).

Comment: @Ned64 there is no given in the output file

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried different methods of redirecting the output, but they don't help. Still no email from the demon

Comment: Where is your `bash` executable located? You have one path in your crontab but another in your script. It's unclear why you think you need to set `SHELL` and `PATH` in the crontab as you don't seem to need these.

Comment: Use cronntab -u work for me

Answer (score 2):

Your cron entry shows you setting the `SHELL` variable to `/bin/bash`.

Unless you've specifically copied it there, the shell won't be available as `/bin/bash`.  The FreeBSD base system does not have `bash`, and if you install it from the FreeBSD package system, it is installed as `/usr/local/bin/bash`
(see [the `hier(7)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier) for info about the FreeBSD directory hierarchy layout).

This means when cron tries to run your script, it won't be able to start a shell to run it, and it will fail.

When you run it manually, you're using your (currently working) shell instead.

Generally, try not to override any environment when configuring crontabs unless absolutely necessary (yes, the path can be a pain sometimes).